# How to return result of function in HTML at Angular?

Tags: angularjs

How to return result in HTML template from fnuction Angular JS?

**HTML:**

```
<div>{{getName({{type}})}}</div>
```

Angular JS:

```
$scope.getName = function (type){
  return 'Bob';
}
```

I need to get `Bob` in `DIV` element

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the second pair of curly braces. `{{getName(type)}}` is sufficient.

Answer (score -1):

As you didn't give the type parameter any value. So I just pass it 1

Try this:

{{getName(1)}}

Comment: This is not the cause for the problem.

Comment: I know the problem is only the braces. I just say that I passed 1 as the parameter for testing purpose

Comment: Still this is not the cause of the problem. The snippet is not the whole document. And you cannot assume that `type` is not definied. Even if it is not defined, angulars interpolations are forgiving, meaning that still *Bob* would be displayed.

Comment: It is, but where in your answer do you mention that? Nowhere. So this answer is NOT useful and does NOT fulfill the needs of an answer.

Comment: Though not mentioned I have given the code. You could have suggested me to explain that instead or could be edited

Comment: I'll remember to mention the reason next time Thanks@Rouby

Comment: Given your code one could easily assume that literals get passed like this, but for other variables you still need the **{{}}**. But that is not the case.